# FluentValidation .Net Core Validator Triggers Twice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Validator:

```
public class UserModelValidator:AbstractValidator<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
            services
            .AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .AddFluentValidation(mvcConfiguration => mvcConfiguration.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<UserModelValidator>());
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp([FromBody]UserModel signupModel)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("On Signup");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(GetModelStateMessage());
        }
        ...
    }

    private string GetModelStateMessage()
    {
        var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
        return message;
    }
```

The validation runs twice. I figure that's not a very practice. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I should mention the Validators are in a class library.

Comment: Hey, can you set a breakpoint and check the call stack to know when exactly the validation is triggered? Also, what does this method do `GetModelStateMessage` ?

Comment: I Edited the post and added it

Comment: Can you please also share how you're registering the `UserModelValidator`. Just to be sure you're not using an interceptor. Thanks!

Comment: I shared the Startup part. Is that what you mean? Stacktrace I'm unable to paste here for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. After looking everywhere I saw an all instance of the Validator. I deleted that and everything got fixed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you've found the issue! If you could extend your answer a bit, so it could be valuable to other users of the site in the future - it would be awesome! For me it's not absolutely clear how "I saw an all instance of the Validator" translates to code. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. the thing was I had a private instance of the UserModelValidator on my controller. This along with the AddFluentValidation on Startup resulted on the double triggering.

Comment: What do you mean @ZionHai? It would really help what you did here. We're facing the same issue right now. Thanks!

Comment: I Had it registered twice on my Startup.cs